# Bluemix MobileFirst 8.0 Dashboard Adapters count

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud

There was a recent update to Bluemix MFP 8.0 service and after that noticing this bug.  I have 6 adapters and on the left nav bar I see only 4 and the count says 4, but when I click on the "Adapters(4)" on the left nav bar, I see all of my 6 adapters on the right side.

Did not see this in the previous version[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a regression. Thanks for letting us know.
There really isn't much that can be done on you rend, just know that we are aware of this and it will be fixed in a hopefully near-future release. Thanks!